# Submitting a single form when there are multiple forms on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I submit a single form while having different forms on a single page?

**FORM 1:**

```
<form action="../../../../../xyz/services/xyzOperation" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" class='form-horizontal page formm' id='uploadForm' style="margin-bottom: -1px;">
```

**FORM 2:**

```
<form action="../../../../../xyz/services/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="final_target" class='form-horizontal page formFinal' id='finalForm'>
```

**JS CODE**

```
document.forms["uploadForm"].submit();
```

I am using the above statement to submit the first form but surprisingly it also submits the second form..

Please help me, as this issue is now becoming so irritating to me.

I have also used the following code but of no avail

```
document.getElementById("uploadForm").submit();
```

THANKS

Comment: Where did you put these statements?

Comment: where you have </form> ?

Comment: closing tags of forms does exist... And Adil I have added these in the body of a simple html page

Answer (score 2):

You can try this...

```
function submitForm(){
 document.formName.action="actionName";
 document.formName.submit();
}


<form method="post" name="formName" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ....
 <input type="button" onclick="submitForm()"/>
<form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Form submissions use the *name* not the *id* attribute to identify unique elements.  Add

```
name = "uploadForm"
name = "finalForm"
```

to their respective elements.

Answer (score 0):

assign name to form tag,

```
<form name="frm1" action="form action"></form>
<form name="frm2" action="form action"></form>
```

to submit first form

```
document.frm1.submit();
```

to submit second form

```
document.frm2.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="UPDATE"/>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="DELETE"/>
</form>
and use $_GET['action'] or $_POST['action'] (depending if you use get or post for form).

if($_POST['action'] == 'DELETE'){
 //.....
} elseif($_POST['action'] == 'UPDATE'){
 //.....
}
```

Comment: If this code work for you, then you should accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign each form with an element id, then you will be able to manipulate which form to upload as per your script.   Id enables DOM to specifically pick the exact form and execute the process.  For example

```
<form id="form1"> blah blah </form>
<form id="form2"> blah blah </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all above mentioned answers but I was unable to succeed, but after that I removed the action attribute of the forms and then used the following code at the time of submission of each form

```
document.uploadFormName.action="../../../../../xyz/services/abc/fileUpload";
document.uploadFormName.submit();
```

Then it was not submitting all the forms on the page.

It is a kind of work around but a good one ;).